# Linq, lambda expression and OrderBy

Tags: linq, lambda, sql-order-by

I have this generic method in my repository:

```
public T GetFirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, Expression<Func<T, object>> keySelector, bool ascending)
{
    if (ascending)
    {
        return dbset.Where(where).OrderBy(keySelector).FirstOrDefault<T>();
    }
    else
    {
        return dbset.Where(where).OrderByDescending(keySelector).FirstOrDefault<T>();
    }
}
```

And I would like to be able to use it like this, where DateCreated is of type DateTime:

```
someRepository.GetFirstOrDefault(m => m.myprop == someValue, m => m.DateCreated, true);
```

and like this, where Id is of type Int:

```
someRepository.GetFirstOrDefault(m => m.myprop == someValue, m => m.Id, true);
```

and like this, where Name is of type string:

```
someRepository.GetFirstOrDefault(m => m.myprop == someValue, m => m.Name, true)
```

However, it gives me the following error when I use it:

**Unable to cast the type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.**

After doing some research, I found out that maybe I have to use a keySelector of type `Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>` or something like that, and this is where I am getting confused. If I declare my method like this, I am not sure where TKey should be coming from:

```
public T GetFirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, bool ascending) { }
```

Am I on the right path? How should my OrderBy clause be declared?

Comment: Which property is of type DateTime?

Comment: Your method name is somewhat confusing.  You're effectively doing a Min/Max function but overloading the name of another kind of method that does something completely different.  I'd be careful with that.

Comment: @ArsenMkrt: All my models derive from a base model that has a DateCreated property which is of type DateTime.

Comment: @JeffMercado Could you elaborate a little bit? What you are saying sounds interesting, but I am not sure what other function I am overloading?

Comment: When I see the method `FirstOrDefault()`, I _expect_ it to return the first item in the collection or the default value for the type if it is empty.  This is a standard LINQ method.  Here you're defining a similarly named method that does something completely different hence the confusion.  The implementation is the pattern typically used to find item in a collection that is a minimum or maximum.  I'd name this method something else.  Some libraries that does this calls it `MinBy()` or `MaxBy()`.  I'd suggest naming it `MinMaxByOrDefault()` or something along those lines.

Comment: @JeffMercado I see. Thanks! When I implemented it, I had in mind the order by DateCreated that I was gonna use, hense the First. But you are right, since this is a generic method, the name should reflect what it is doing in "general".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems this method is part of a generic class, which is where the type parameter `T` is coming from. If you need another type parameter just for this method, you have to make the method itself generic:

```
public T GetFirstOrDefault<TKey>(
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> where,
    Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector,
    bool ascending)
```

You can then call it and specify the parameter explicitly:

```
someRepository.GetFirstOrDefault<string>(m => m.myprop == someValue, m => m.Name, true)
```

Or let the compiler infer it:

```
someRepository.GetFirstOrDefault(m => m.myprop == someValue, m => m.Name, true)
```

(Note that you certainly don't want assignment `=` in the first lambda, you want `==`. Fortunately, your code wouldn't even compile.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations! I thought I had tried that and that it did not work, but I must have done something a bit different, because now it is working.